# SQL Server Agent appears to be treating sysprocesses (and dm_exec_sessions) differently

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-agent, system-tables

I have a watchdog process that runs via a SQL Agent job to manage some custom tasks. One of the checks is that the process no longer exists:

```
UPDATE R
SET IsOrphaned = 1, DebugTimestampUtc = GETUTCDATE()
FROM
    RequestTable AS R
    LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses AS P ON
        P.spid = R.SPID
WHERE P.spid IS NULL
```

In SSMS, I run this statement then close the query window before it completes (cancelling the query):

```
INSERT INTO RequestTable(SPID, CreateTimestampUtc, ...)
SELECT @@SPID, GETUTCDATE(), ...
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30.000'
```

When I manually run the query to flag orphans in SSMS it matches on the row, **but my job does not**, as is evidenced by the `RequestTable` not getting the row marked as orphaned. The job history shows it running as scheduled without any errors, taking negligible runtime (< 1 second).

Furthermore, when I augment the orphan detection statement to also find records where `P.status = 'sleeping'` it immediately detects when I cancel the `INSERT ... WAITFOR ...` query (and keep the query window open).

Is there some subtle behavior of SQL Server causing this apparently-inconsistent state of the `sys.sysprocesses` table between SSMS and SQL Agent? I have also tried with and without a NOLOCK query hint on `RequestTable`.

I'm running on SQL Server 2014 in compatibility mode for 2008R2.

(Note that using [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) instead still behaves the same)

Thanks.

P.S. The purpose of this is to serialize asynchronous processes that have concurrency issues. Perhaps there is also a better manner to do this (without being able to fix the asynchronous processes)?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue - SQL Server Agent isn't going to treat a specific view differently than any other user/login with the same access. But `sysprocesses` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 and you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: When I switch to using `sys.dm_exec_sessions` it behaves the same, weird way.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that would solve the issue. It may prevent others, though, including future breakage.

Comment: I'm thinking that you are running into a subtle but expected behavior. Specifically - when the job kicks off, what SPID is it getting?  To check this: Run your INSERT query in a dozen different windows. Kill them all, and close the windows. Then let the job run. It should leave only one SPID unflagged.

Comment: To avoid capturing your own process, add a filter like `session_id <> @@SPID`.

Comment: Aha, so you're saying that when the job runs, it reuses the SPID of the process (query window) that I just disconnected!

Comment: It's quite possible, yes.

Comment: That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by [Aaron](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand), the current session was being caught, because they are reused in the connection pool.

The solution is to filter it out:

```
AND session_id <> @@SPID
```